# auto converting json to object in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I search google and stackoverflow but did not find some auto converting lib like in C#

I need something in dart-flutter alternative to this code in C#

```
    string jsonTokenData = "{my token json data}";
    TokenModel getTokenModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetTokenModel>(jsonTokenData);
```

> Update

- I read the Documentation and I know how to map models with json
- this question to who know how Newtonsoft lib work on C#
- if you do not know Newtonsoft: the Idea is to convert json data to a model automatically without writing map for each model. Also I know there is a tool to create that map with json for each model automatically but still make code ridiculous.

> Update2: as I get a suggestion from community for a similar question that not answer my question. so this is a another explanation:

I have a lot of models these models are updated by time as clients requested or adding new features to some models.
so when an update happen I just need to add the extra properties that has been added to these models, I do not need to warry every time about mapping, spell mistaken or using some tools again to regenerate these codes.

so I'm asking for a function that take two parameters

- first one is the type of the model
- second one the json string that hold the data

**[then in return is an object instance of the passed type]**

for simple example if I have this class:

```
class Car {
    String name;
    String type;
}
```

Then I could keep it clean this way without getting it dart with other methods:

```
Car({
        this.name,
        this.type,
    });

    factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Car(
        name: json["name"],
        type: json["type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "type": type,
    };
```

by the way lib in C# is also take care about arrays, lists and nested classes

I hope this time it explained well

Comment: Could you address my comment on my answer? I already understand what your C# method is doing, but I would like to know how and what the issue with the method I proposed is.

Comment: it is a Lib for C# .net
that automatically Create instance and retrieve it's properties of the a given type <GetTokenModel>
then fetch data from json string and return that instance with the fetched data

Comment: And how does it do this automatically? What if the properties contained in the JSON don't match up with the fields of the object? How is this result different from what my answer would achieve? Please see my answer.

Comment: I think I have to do my own lib if now one have the answer by using import 'dart:mirrors'; it should do the job I will try with it

Comment: " it's return null values for not matching keys" and what does Newtonsoft do when there aren't matching fields? I'm trying to understand the behavior of Newtonsoft to find an alternative in dart. If you don't explain to me in detail what the exact behavior you want, it's very difficult to help without you rejecting any solution I offer. If you're simply asking for a library that will do the equivalent the simple answer is: it likely doesn't exist.

Comment: " if now one have the answer by using import 'dart:mirrors'" Your question implies you want to use flutter. `dart:mirrors` is disabled in flutter and no workable solution will come out of using that.

Comment: then I will stick with same way of mapping. that I already knew

Comment: Please add that method as an answer to your question so that future users can follow.

Comment: What is your expected behavior when there is a misspelling? How does your C# library know to map your misspelling to the correct field?

Comment: I've recently added this package https://pub.dev/packages/jsonize, you can implement the Jsonizable interface in your own data classes and then your objects can go wherever in whatever data structure.

Comment: There is still no way to do automatic JSON parsing in Flutter. Looking forward for a Newtonsoft-like library for Flutter. Initializing and parsing model classes requires tooo much code in the class constructor. This should change.

Answer (score 2):

I've added a new Dart package to [Jsonize](https://pub.dev/packages/jsonize) custom classes within any data structure.

This is how your Car example would look like:

```
import 'package:jsonize/jsonize.dart';

class Car implements Jsonizable<Car> {
  final String name;
  final String type;
  Car({required this.name, required this.type});

  // Jsonizable implementation
  factory Car.empty() => Car(name: "", type: "");

  @override
  String get jsonClassCode => "car";

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": name, "type": type};

  @override
  Car? fromJson(value) => Car(name: value["name"], type: value["type"]);
}

void main() {
  // Register classes
  Jsonize.registerClass(Car.empty());

  // Now you can jsonize it wherever
  Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
    "my_car": Car(name: "Jessie", type: "Tesla"),
    "purchase_dt": DateTime.now(),
  };
  var jsonRep = Jsonize.toJson(myMap);
  var hereIsMyMap = Jsonize.fromJson(jsonRep);
  print(hereIsMyMap);

  List<dynamic> myList = [
    Car(name: "Jessie", type: "Tesla"),
    Car(name: "Bob", type: "Ford"),
  ];
  jsonRep = Jsonize.toJson(myList);
  var hereIsMyList = Jsonize.fromJson(jsonRep);
  print(hereIsMyList);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just import **dart:convert library** like this :

```
 import 'dart:convert';
```

Then use this code :

```
json.decode(json)
```

Take a look at this link : [dart:convert library](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html)

Answer (score -2):

Doing some research would allow you to not ask here on SO.

JSON decoding is well documented on the [flutter site](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json). It points to using the [`jsonDecode` function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html), which parses the `String` and returns the resulting JSON object.

```dart
String jsonTokenData = "{my token json data}";
dynamic json = jsonDecode(jsonTokenData);
```

You can pass the decoded object to a custom constructor of your object like `.fromJson`, which accepts a `Map`/`List` depending on your JSON data.

If for some reason creating a constructor to accept JSON data would be too much work/typing or if you're having trouble doing it yourself, you can use a JSON to Dart service like [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).

Comment: @AbduImam And how is this different? `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetTokenModel>(jsonTokenData);` does the exact same thing except you can specify the object to deserialize to. Choosing the object to deserialize to is not possible in dart. Making a custom constructor in addition to `jsonDecode` is the only way to create an object from a JSON.

Comment: yes and we still need to do mapping, and that it is what I need to avoid.
so that what I'm ask if there is a lib for that or how some one can create dynamic mapping using staff like System.Reflection in dot net framework of C#.

Comment: @AbduImam I'm still unclear of the differences. You should try to put what you're trying to do in universal or dart terms as there isn't necessarily a plethora of developers available to answer your question that are skilled in both dart and C#

Comment: yes I did update my question explaining how Newtonsoft work

Comment: @AbduImam And how does Newtonsoft do this internally? What does it do with JSON data that allows it to attribute data to certain properties? Why is creating a constructor to handle what `jsonDecode` returns a problem?

Comment: @AbduImam I have edited my answer to include a JSON to Dart converter that would reduce the work involved in creating a constructor for your JSON.

Comment: @AbduImam I have made another edit that adds some more detail directly into the answer instead of in the comments.